# How to escape apostrophe in VBA-excel

Tags: vba, excel, ado

For the column staffID

there is some data : S19, S18,S17,225 ,229,059 ,077

However, some data has been typed (' ) <--apostrophe  before the data .

I guess this is for enter the 0

Then I use ADO -sql. I find that I cant fully group by the data because apostrophe before the data.( I guess this the reason)

Hence, how to escape all apostrophe in the excel in vba ?

Remark: the column is B

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking but in Excel you escape ' with '.  So, if you want ' to display in a cell, you actually have to type '' in that cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the format of column b to text, and the replace all the ' signs with nothing.. Changing the format to text will help you preserve the zero values in text like 077 etc....